# EPPlus Calculate Excel Worksheet.Cells[3, 2].Value returns "#value"

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I am using the Worksheet and the workbook and calling the calculate() method for every sheet and for the workbook:

```
foreach (var worksheet in eppWorlSheets)
            {
                worksheet.Calculate();
            }
            this.eppWorkBook.Calculate();
```

When trying to get the value of some calculated cells that contains double it returns #value! as a string
using the below code

```
Worksheet.Cells[3, 2].Value.ToString());
```

Even the Text property return #value! and the Value property without "ToString()"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I try it, it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, it's a Cell that contains a formula: "=Amount*Percentage", both amount and percentage are numeric, but I am not sure if the EPPlus read it as number or no, finally I am returning to Excel Interop because EPPlus doesn't support some Excel functions, Thank you